# Foreach not getting all the values from gridview because of datatable pagination

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, foreach, datatable

So I have a function that loops through a GridView, which is using a JQuery DataTable with pagination. It shows ten rows for every page, so it is necessary to edit all the textboxes you want and click on a button named "Save" that calls the function mentioned before. The issue is that only the page that is displayed on the screen at the moment of clicking on the button "Save" is sending the textbox values and not all gridview texbox instead. For instance, if I edit "gridview page 1", "gridview page 2" and "gridview page 3" fields and click on the button "Save" while "gridview page 3" is displayed then "gridview page 1" and "gridview page 2" textbox values are not saved. If I'm explaining myself wrongly let me know please.

ASPX Inline code

```
<asp:GridView ID="grvServicio" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" class="display" >
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="intIdServicio" HeaderText="ID" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="vchServicio" HeaderText="Servicio" />           
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Cantidad">      
            <ItemTemplate>                 
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtCantidad" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" Text='<%# Bind("intCantidad")%>'></asp:TextBox>              
            </ItemTemplate>         
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Precio">      
            <ItemTemplate>                 
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtPrecio" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" Text='<%# Bind("decPrecio")%>'></asp:TextBox>              
            </ItemTemplate>         
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Estatus">
            <ItemTemplate>  
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkServEstatus" Checked='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("intEstatus"))%>' enabled="true" runat="server" CssClass="ChkBoxClass"/>                  
            </ItemTemplate> 
        </asp:TemplateField> 
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

ASPX Behind code (I've removed the code saving process but if necessary let me know)

```
protected void btnGuardarServicio_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (GridViewRow row in grvServicio.Rows)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < grvServicio.Columns.Count; i++)
            {                   
                string idEvento = row.Cells[0].Text;
                TextBox cant = (TextBox)row.Cells[2].FindControl("txtCantidad");
                TextBox prec = (TextBox)row.Cells[3].FindControl("txtPrecio");
                prec.Text = prec.Text.Replace(",", ".");

            }
        }
}
```

[Here is how my GridView looks like using datatable JQuery plug-in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r1hZo.png)

Answer (score 0):

With a paginated grid, data is rendered and loaded (if it is a server -side pagination) only when you change the page. Maybe you can save the data on value changed event so when you change to next page and back again you have data updated.